# Can Spring Integration cause a Reactive Application to block?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I’m using Project Reactor for a non-blocking IO data pipeline, and I’m thinking of using Spring Integration as an abstraction layer to manage all of the flows and components in my pipeline. I’m currently implementing a Kafka consumer with Project Reactor and I’m starting to wonder whether the Spring Integration wrap can damage my pipeline in terms of blocking and back-pressure.

I would like to know if is considered safe to use Spring Integration and its classes in a full non blocking application, and if there’s any traps I should note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases Spring Integration components are stateless, so they are safe to use in multi-threaded (or non-blocking) environment. You may suffer some concerns if you use a specific channel adapter which really does a blocking IO operation, e.g. file writing or JDBC INSERT. In this cases you would need to consider to switch to a different thread for this type of operations to not block your reactive flow.

See respective recipe in Project Reactor: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

For that thread switching purpose Spring Integration provides an `ExecutorChannel` and `QueueChannel` implementations. However the `FluxMessageChannel` will fit in some cases pretty well.

The limited back-pressure does not make sense in Spring Integration solution since everything is considered as a stream, infinite flow of data. Therefore in most cases Spring Integration relies on the natural back-pressure where we don't request more until we process the current.

Please, give it a try and don't hesitate coming back to us with some feedback!

Comment: Thanks !! What exactly did you mean by “we don’t request more until we process the current”? It is a SI feature, or does it means that if the source has a back pressure capabilities, SI won’t interrupt?

Comment: What is "source back pressure capabilities" in your understanding? My point is that there is no request limits in SI. Just because it is for streaming and hot sources. Therefore any reactive features in SI even if they request it is `Long.MAX_VALUE` - no limit. And whatever could be back-pressured is just natural, when the current thread (subscriber) performs some logic for an in-flight data. I'm not sure why to talk too much about back-pressure where you just need to concentrate on a logic of your application based on Reactor operators and Spring Integration reactive features.

Comment: The reason I focused on this was just to make sure I understand correctly. Thanks a lot for your help!